# Java: call a class by ID

Tags: java

I have a class "Class1" which implements Observer and contains a thread like this:

```
class Class1 implements Observer {

    String id = null;
    Object lockObject = new Object();

    public Class1(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        theThread.start();
    }

    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
        lockObject.notify();
    }

    Thread theThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                lockObject.wait();
                printID();
            }
        }
    };

    public void printID() {
        System.out.println( /*the ID of this class*/ + " was called");
    }
}
```

and another, "Class2" which extends Observable and calls the first class:

```
class Class2 extends Observable {
    public Class2() {
        addObserver("ID_THREAD_ONE"); //Though it takes a class as parameter
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new Class1("ID_THREAD_ONE");
        new Class2();
    }
}
```

Of course the code wont work because the method `addObserver()` takes an object of a class as parameter (In this case the object of `Class1`).
But I wanted to know if there was a way to make the addObserver method add an Object of a class by a before defined "class-id".

I know it would be easier to just do it like: `addObserver(new Class1())`, but i cant for some reason (which is also why i need to use id's).

Any answers are appreciated and thanks in advance,

cheers,

Julien

Comment: It is possible, but it sounds like you thinking of wrong solution to your problem. Maybe if you describe the actual problem, we can provide better help. Other than that, what @Mark said.

Comment: Well the problem is that when the "real" program is launched at first some hundred Class1-threads are launched via. a for-loop or so and afterwards the classes are added to Class2; like the first 20 are added to the first instance of Class2 and the next 80 to another of Class2.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to specify why your ID's are necessary. If they're to be used for some sort of mapping I guess they could stay as is.

As for the actual Observer/Observable, since both your classes are instanciated from the Main class, I think this is what you're looking for:

In your `Class2` you have to include a `Class1` instance in your constructor.

```
class Class2 extends Observable {
    public Class2(Class1 observer) {
        addObserver(observer);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Then, in your `Main`, simply pass the `Class1` instance in the `Class2` constructor like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class2(new Class1("someID"));
    }
}
```

`"someID"` is there just in case you'd need it for something else, but other than that, no need to use ID's in the Observer.

Comment: A great thank you for the quick reply. I think that was exactly what I was looking for (just thought way to complicated). :)

Comment: @Julien Great ! Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful. As for your comment on your OP, if my solution didn't help you figure it out, I can post an edit concerning the mapping of the ~100 instances, but I bet you will figure it out easily.

Comment: Already got the hang of it, but thanks anyway Mat. And yes the solution was way to easy then being worth a question here. ^^